# Swagger-ui.html not showing api list

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I'm using spring boot + swagger 2 for documenting all the REST API .I'm able to list all the api of a controller when i have the below project structure.

[image]

If i move the swaggerconfig.java to the config package then i'm not able to list all api of a controller.i'm getting
[image]

This is my **SwaggerConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
//@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.javainuse.swaggertest")
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket postsApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).groupName("public-api")
                .apiInfo(apiInfo()).select().paths(postPaths()).build();
    }

    private Predicate<String> postPaths() {
        return or(regex("/api/posts.*"), regex("/api/javainuse.*"));
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("JavaInUse API")
                .description("JavaInUse API reference for developers")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("http://javainuse.com")
                .contact("javainuse@gmail.com").license("JavaInUse License")
                .licenseUrl("javainuse@gmail.com").version("1.0").build();
    }

}
```

What i'm doing wrong

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed the problem. The problem is browser cache. I just cleared all the cache, and then I'm able to get the swagger-ui.html with all api list.

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me is:

```
    @Bean
    public Docket customImplementation(){
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("your base package"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
```

notice paths is not specific, its any.

Answer (score 1):

This solved my issue.

Add .pathMapping("/") in the Docket

```
return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
              .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
              .paths(PathSelectors.any())
              .build()
              .pathMapping("/");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).apiInfo(apiInfo()).select() 
                  .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.boot")))
                  .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.cloud")))
                  .apis(Predicates.not(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("org.springframework.security")))
                     .build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the OP issue was solved already, I stumbled upon this thread and my solution was somewhat different. Here it is for others should they find themselves in the same position:

I had the same issue, but with using swagger-codegen-maven-plugin (v3)
The API is defined in a api.yml specification file and I generate the interface and models with the plugin.

It has an option to also generate a controller, in which case it was showing in the UI. However when I configure the controllers to be ignored/skipped for generation and just implement my own it was not showing.

The problem was the package. The plugin also auto generates the SwaggerDocumentationConfig class which includes all controllers from the API package that is configured. My own controllers had to be in the exact same package.

Code snippets to clarify:

In my pom.xml I have configured the plugin with:

```xml
<apiPackage>a.b.c.spec.api</apiPackage>
```

The auto generated SwaggerDocumentationConfig class contains:

```java
  @Bean
  public Docket customImplementation() {
    return (new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)).select()
      .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors
        .basePackage("a.b.c.spec.api"))
      .build().apiInfo(this.apiInfo());
  }
```

My controller lives in the package `a.b.c.api` so I had to change the apiPackage property to align and the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on maven based Java Spring Boot project.
In my case, it was a version mismatch of swagger and swagger-ui dependency in pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario, it's because of the @Profile("dev") configuration in SwaggerConfig limited for dev profile only, while I was running with another profile.

Answer (score 0):

Checking versions of Swagger-UI and springfox-swagger2 in pox.xml

Adding @EnableSwagger2 in application.java helped.

Comment: Can you give more details about why makes those changes, check version to be at which values ... Please [edit] your answer